# Google Multiple Sign-ins - Is there a way to specify the account in the URL?

Tags: gmail, google-docs, google-apps, google-account

We recently switched our team to Google Apps and with that, everyone got a Google Apps account . However, for those of us with a GMail account as well, this makes it so that bringing up Gmail in your browser opens up either your personal account or your Google apps account.

Even though GMail has multiple Sign-ins enabled for both of my accounts, I still have to spend time switching through both accounts.

I was wondering if there was a way to specify the account I wanted to use in the URL directly, which would allow me to create a bookmark for GMail for both of these accounts:

something like:

```
http://mail.google.com?a=firstaccount@gmail.com
http://mail.google.com?a=workaccount@googleappsdomain.com
```

I just don't believe anyone at Google has never thought of this! :-)
The same question applies to all of Google's services too I guess (docs, sites, etc...)

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/49168/809 works for me

Comment: Solution referenced by @CADbloke is still valid and solved the same question for me today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an access to multiple gmail adresse you can use this :

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth?continue=http://mail.google.com/gmail&service=mail&Email=yourname@gmail.com

Answer (score 5):

`https://mail.google.com/a/googleappsdomain.com/`

This works like a charm, with one exception: regular gmail.com accounts. `https://mail.google.com/mail/` will direct you to the inbox for whichever account you logged in as first.  My work around has been to make sure I log into my personal e-mail first (but this at least avoids having to log into the rest in a specific order).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this URL to open from `username@gmail.com`

https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https://mail.google.com&Email=username@gmail.com