# Google multiple accounts - In URL selection by email instead of by user number

Tags: url, google-account

When accessing multiple Google accounts from the browser, with multiple accounts logged in, Google will allow selecting the proper account using a number that identifies the chronologically logged in user, with the syntax:

```
https://<service-name>/u/<user-number>/
```

For instance:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
https://contacts.google.com/u/2/preview/all
```

I wonder if is there a way to use an URL where the user-number is replaced with the user email....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466064/google-multiple-sign-ins-is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-account-in-the-url for a similar discussion.

Answer (score 6):

[This seems to work](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/2hEi6wcgW8M) for Gmail

On Desktop:
https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2Fu%2F%3Fauthuser%3DUSERNAME%40DOMAIN&service=mail&Email=USERNAME@DOMAIN

For mobile:

https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2Fmu%2Fmp%2F%3Fauthuser%3DUSERNAME%40DOMAIN&service=mail&Email=USERNAME@DOMAIN

Comment: This is the only solution that is guaranteed to open Gmail for that one user. Others, like an `authuser` parameter or appending `/b/<email>` to the path, even the `ServiceLogin` solution documented [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97952/60622) will fail if the user is already logged in but not in the intended account.

Comment: Shorter version: `https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=YOUR_URL&Email=USERNAME@gmail.com`

Answer (score 5):

Use this solution `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/?authuser=user@gmail.com`

Taken from this link https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18959/can-i-form-a-direct-url-to-a-particular-gmail-account/49168#49168

Comment: This doesn't open the correct account if you are logged into multiple ones.

Comment: @OliverDixon Have you tried other solutions from link?

Answer (score 0):

For Google calendar, use:

https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fcalendar.google.com%2Fcalendar%2Fb%2FUSERNAME%40DOMAIN&Email=USERNAME@DOMAIN

Thats what I got from altering the Riccardo's URL.

Comment: How it's related with the question?

Comment: Ah, the link was not proper, it was missing "&Email=USERNAME@DOMAIN" at the end of the URL. I edited the response accordingly.

Comment: @VasylLyashkevych, it's related because Riccardo was asking about the way to use the user's email in Google services URL, instead of numbers (0, 1, ..). Riccardo then came up with the URL for Gmail, in which you replace USERNAME and DOMAIN and it works. I then presented similar URL, but for Google Calendar.